# HTML Form GET method with previous get parameters

Tags: php, html

I have a form on a page with get parameters:
index.php?PageID=12

I then have a multiple forms on that page which build up the page details as the user selects the details.

My problem is when the form is posted the Get overwrites other get parameters.

I can use post but then can only post the information back once as the post values are wiped when the next form is submitted;

the idea is the forms build up a address as such;

1. `?PageID=12`
2. `?PageID=12&Section=48`
3. `?PageID=12&Section=48&Event=1456`

and so on as the user selects more items.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't I feel silly,

Just use the post method and have a large form with multiple ways to submit the data, each time the data is submitted, the post params get posted back.

A little error checking to check for changed responses

Comment: Use the gets to populate hidden fields for the next form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For forms with `method=get` the query string parameters specified in `action` attribute are ignored. Add such parameters as hidden form fields:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="PageID"  value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="Section" value="48">
<input type="hidden" name="Event"   value="1456">
</form>
```

You can use server-side script or JavaScript to add the query string parameters as hidden form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Put the incoming $_GET params in hidden fields

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below code in which you can initialize the parameter that already  required to post

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
```

Here all the parameter will join with index.php?.......

So if you required to pass some parameter by default then you can write index.php?para=1......

But don not leave it blank form action value, by default it will consider the same url that is in address bar.

May this will help you .........:)