# HTML Form action value not working

Tags: html, forms

I have 2 files. `index.php` and `login.php`. In `index.php` I have a form with a submit button that should take me to `login.php`.

```
<form action="login.php?redirect=update.php">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Update Availability"/>
</form>
```

`login.php` is supposed to redirect me to the GET value of `redirect`. However, when I click submit in `index.php` it takes me to `login.php?`. Why is this? How can I get it to take me to the desired page with the correct GET values? I should be expecting `login.php?redirect=update.php`

**Note:** I have already tried to use a `hidden` form value like this:

```
<form action="login.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="update.php"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Update Availability"/>
</form>
```

but to no avail

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Here is the PHP code inside `login.php` which checks to make sure the GET value `redirect` exists.

```
if ( !(isset($_GET["redirect"]))){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('YOU DO NOT HAVE A REDIRECT');</script>";
    //header("Location: index.php");
    //die();
} else {
    if (isset($_SESSION["username"])){
        header("Location: " . $_GET["redirect"]);
        die();
    }
}
```

**Edit2:** The issue here is not why it is not redirecting me, the issue is why is it when I click the button in `index.php` does it take me to `login.php?` and not `login.php?redirect=update.php`. I know it will not automatically redirect me.

**Edit3:** When trying the style as in the **Note**, it was suddenly working again. I then did further tests to find out if I could replicate the problem once again, and did so. `login.php` redirects to a page called `update.php` which the user inputs some data and then sends said data to another page called `adduser.php` (I know this could possibly be rewritten to make it shorter, but for now I'm trying to get a basic version working). In `adduser.php`, it will add the data specified by the user to a database, and then redirect to `index.php`. But once redirected back to `index.php`, I can no longer click the link to go to `login.php` once again. It instantly redirects me back to `index.php` (as the PHP code should if it doesn't recognize a GET `redirect` value). I am totally stumped as to why this is happening, any thoughts?

Comment: You should show your php code. It's not like by putting a `redirect` parameter on your url you automatically obtain a redirect.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The PHP code in this instance is not really relevant. All it does is check if `$_GET["redirect"]` exists.

Comment: Ok, but why do you expect a redirect to happen? Or are you saying that in the php code `$_GET["redirect"]` does not contain the correct value?

Comment: `login.php` is used to log the user in, and when they have logged in, it will then redirect them to a specific page.

Comment: 1: that's not what you've written in your question, please amend it. 2: really, we can't guess what you're doing on the backend. Please show the code.

Comment: _“However, when I click submit in index.php it takes me to login.php?. Why is this?”_ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537783/1427878

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))` are you sure the problem is not here, since there is no alternative branch?

Comment: @CBroe But as you can see I do not have `method="GET"` inside the form. :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Please see edit2.

Comment: _“But as you can see I do not have method="GET" inside the form. :)”_ - GET is the default, when `method` is not specified ...

Comment: @CBroe Edit3 should share some more details on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

on login.php page you must first check isset($_GET['redirect') if is set then redirect to another page like header('Location:update.php');